# How to remove a bolt if you can’t reach the other side to hold it in place?

Tags: screws, bolts

The bolt is turning but the problem is that so is the screw. I need to hold the screw tight from the other side, but I can’t reach it because it’s in a one inch wide crevice. The only solution I can think of is to buy a really long, like 12-16”-long handle wrench, to hold the screw tight in the crevice. [image]
[image]

Comment: The nut looks like a nylon-filled lock nut (Nylok nut) and I’m afraid you won’t get it loose unless you can hold/turn the nut.

Comment: Short wrench + stick and judicious amount of tape == long wrench.

Comment: drill a hole in the end of the bolt ... cut threads with a tap ... screw in a bolt

Comment: cut a slot in the end of the bolt, then turn it with a slotted screwdriver while holding the nut with a wrench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that it is not required to keep the bolt after the removal, consider to create a center-punch mark on the bolt. Hold the nut with a locking pliers and apply a small diameter drill bit (with drill motor) and begin to drill out the bolt.

The torque applied by the drill bit will be in the desired direction to release the bolt. The ideal circumstance will result in the drill creating a hole of substantial length inside the bolt. The small diameter bit should then be exchanged for a larger diameter bit, as this will "catch" the edges of the previous hole and spin out the bolt.

At the very worst, it will be necessary to drill the nut completely free of the bolt.

Answer (score 2):

The bolt has a lock washer under its head so take a screwdriver or pry bar and apply outward force to the washer you can get to and try to turn the nut you can get to. Hopefully the force you apply will cause the lock washer to grab the bolt enough so you can turn the nut.

Comment: It looks like the nut is a lock nut  (Nylok nut) which means that it will be difficult to remove it without holding or turning the nut itself. I don’t think your idea will work.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the simple inelegant solution is the best one.

Get a box wrench for the nut and a pipe that fits over the wrench... Or duct tape a long bar to the wrench, or something.

Now you have a very long handled wrench.

Edit: not sure why the downvote. All the OP needs is a box wrench with a long handle.

Comment: The cheater bar is not to add torque but to be able the reach the nut. The OP can turn the bolt but cannot reach the locknut to hold it because their wrench is too short

Answer (score 1):

I have had success by using a junior hacksaw to cut a slot into the bolt (and nut at the same time).

Then hold the bolt with a small screwdriver.

You can also remove the nyloc bit as well.